# SetInterval and clearInterval explanation

Tags: javascript

```
var fps = 30;
var drawInterval;

imageSprite.addEventListener('load',init,false);

function init() {
    drawBg();
    startDrawing();
}

function draw() {        
    clearJet();
    drawJet();
}

function startDrawing() {
    stopDrawing();
    drawInterval = setInterval(draw,1000 / fps);
}

function stopDrawing() {
    clearInterval(drawInterval);
}
```

Can anybody explain why do we execute the function stopDrawing() before drawInetrval and how will this code execute.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially with `clearInternal` you are stopping the interval referenced by `drawInterval`.

You could look at it as if it were setting `drawInterval = null`.

That is done to prevent multiple intervals firing: each time `startDrawing` is called, you reset the current ongoing interval and start a new one that will fire in 1000/fps milliseconds, i.e. `drawInterval` will fire `1000/fps` milliseconds after `startDrawing` is called for the last time.

Comment: does that mean that the `startDrawing()` function is called multiple times or that the refrence is firing `setInterval(draw,1000 / fps)` multiple times? and if it is why do we use `stopDrawing()`function first and not after the interval has been fired.

Comment: `startDrawing` is called every time `imageSprite` finishes loading its content. if you call `stopDrawing` after starting the interval, you simply stop it immediately - this is not what you want. calling `stopDrawing` before actually starting the interval means that if the interval was already running it gets stopped, and a new one starts after `1000/fps` milliseconds (and since it is an interval it will continuously fire every `1000/fps`ms.

Answer (score 0):

It is simply clearing the interval so that you are not running multiple intervals at the same time.